# Insert query with array for column and values

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to insert a set of data with flexible input.

For example,

```
INSERT INTO table (column[]) VALUES (values[])
```

How do I suppose to do in order to let this code work successfully?

> SOLUTION:

Thanks for everyone who try to answer me, but I am actually solved it by using String.Join
I just want to create a class file that contain add,edit,delete query for me to use in every form I created. And when I want to use the query class file I can insert my data more flexible.

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you seriously treating column and values as a string array in an sql query?

Comment: What you mean "flexible input"? Please edit to add more detailed explanation of what you want to try with INSERT command.

Comment: Explain you sample input, your sample table structure and sample output

Answer (score -1):

if i understood you problem correctly, you can find solution here
[Insert XML formed Data into Table (SQL)](http://fordotnetdev.blogspot.com/2017/04/insert-xml-formed-data-into-table-sql.html)